# Rotating panel in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, rotation, gdi+

I'm making a game C#, which is a new language to me.

I want to make a panel rotate as I hold down a key on the keyboard. When the key is released the panel should stop rotating.

I looked through the internet, and found GDI+ but I don't quite understand it. This is the website: https://web.archive.org/web/20141229192143/http://bobpowell.net/drawing_an_image.aspx

I've read about the GDI+ but I don't know how to use it in my case where I have the panel in the project already and how to add it.

This is the code for rotating but everything gets underlined when I put it in my program.

```
mx.Rotate(-30);
g.Transform = mx;
g.DrawImage(img,new Point(100,50));
```

I don't really understand what the `mx.rotate` line means, nor how I should update it to achieve the rotation while the key is pressed.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with it?

I'm using Visual studio 2008.

Comment: I never understand how so many people new to C# end up trying to make a game... its like trying to fall before you have climbed the mountain

Comment: @musefan, whilst I agree with your sentiments I suspect it has something to do with the attraction of having a game at the end of your hard work, rather than a more mundane Phone/Address application.

Comment: @musefan It's more the fact that they are trying to write a game in winforms that confuses me, but I fully appreciate that XNA Game Studio is another step up (http://create.msdn.com/en-us/resources/downloads).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learning C# and Windows Forms, yet another book thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007756/learning-c-sharp-and-windows-forms-yet-another-book-thread)

Comment: @musefan - I think that games are one of the best things with which to start learning programming. They're both challenging and fun. And you don't have to try and make Crysis at your first go. Even a simple textmode blackjack game is quite educational.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a line from the original code:

```
Matrix mx = new Matrix();
```

Add this to your code, and it should work.  This will draw your image at an angle, just like in the original document.  If you want the user to see the panel rotating, you're probably best off using a timer to increment the angle of rotation and re-draw.

Comment: Yes but Im trying to ad a picture from a file: This the code for getting the picture and rotating it. But I get everything underlined and with errors.  
Here is the code with errors:
 https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-fTuFv3ByByY/TrAFhonVAxI/AAAAAAAACAQ/LNuXD0tKJgM/s696/Capture.jpg

Comment: As @Mickey said, you were missing a namespace declaration.  If you've got Visual Studio, in most cases you can just put the cursor over the unresolved type and hit Shift-Alt-F10 - you'll get a prompt with a list of any matching namespaces, if there are any from your project's current list of references.  If you prefer mice to keyboards, click on the little blue rectangle that appears and you'll get the same options.

Answer (score 2):

You had a few errors in your code. Here is a working example of drawing the rotate image from the `Paint` event.

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) 
{
    var matrix = new Matrix();
    var image = Image.FromFile("c:\\img\\your-image.png");

    matrix.Rotate(-30);
    e.Graphics.Transform = matrix;
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, new Point(100, 100));
}
```

Comment: still 1 error: 
Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Matrix' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You're missing the using statement for System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Comment: Thanks :) That worked. Please leave this thread open because maybe i will still need some help. :)

Comment: You should accept the answer and open a new question if you have a different one.